# implicit coercion when using popupmanager in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I had to reformat my question because I realized I was using incorrect flex method. But still a similar issue occurs:

```
        private function passForm():void {


            PopUpManager.addPopUp(passTitleWindow, this, true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(passTitleWindow);


        } 

                            <s:Button includeIn="Detail" x="10" y="329" 
                                  id= "btn1"
                                  label="Pass"
                                  click="passForm()" 
                                  visible="{hasScreen}" />
```

I click and popup does not display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate an item based on it's `id`.  Make your TitleWindow into another class and instantiate that.

**PassTitleWindow.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TitleWindow
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    title="Pass"
    layout="vertical"
    width="480"
    height="240"
    titleStyleName="titleText"
    backgroundColor="white"
    backgroundAlpha="1.0"
    borderColor="white"
    borderAlpha="1.0"
    cornerRadius="0"
    showCloseButton="true"
    implements="mx.core.IDataRenderer">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var _data:Object;
            [Bindable(event="dataChange")]
            /**
             *  implementing mx.core.IDataRenderer.
             *  Set this value from outside
             */
            public function get data():Object
            {
                return _data;
            }

            /**
             *  @private
             */
            public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                if (_data == value) 
                    return;
                _data = value;
                dispatchEvent(new Event("dataChange"));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Text text="Please fill out the following criteria and then click continue."
        width="100%"
        styleName="headingText"/>

    <mx:Form x="-12" y="150" id="passView">

        <mx:FormItem label="Age" >
            <s:TextInput id="ageTextInput" "@{data.age}"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem label="Grade" >
            <s:TextInput id="gradeTextInput"/>
        </mx:FormItem>

    </mx:Form>

</mx:TitleWindow>
```

**SampleApp.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            protected var passWindow:PassTitleWindow = new PassTitleWindow;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler():void
            {
                createForm();
            }

            protected function createForm():void
            {
                passWindow = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, PassTitleWindow, true) as PassTitleWindow;
                passWindow.data = studentGrid.selectedItem;
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(passWindow);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: Thanks for response. Problem I was having with that approach was that in another component, I was getting studentsGrid is undefined method:

<s:TextInput id="ageTextInput" text="@{studentsGrid.selectedItem.age}"/>

The reason why is studentsgrid is defined in application and not component and I guess the component can't communicate with the datagrid in application.

Comment: I see.  Its best practice to separate your data so the item renderers don't have to reference their parent.  You can do that by implementing IDataRenderer (one get/set method for "data"), and setting the data to the selected item.  I've updated the code to show that.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Finally got it to update the correct item, courtesy of your advice and this link: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_7.html. I don't think I fully comprehend this line:  dispatchEvent(new Event("dataChange")). But I will read the article again and see if it offers any insights. Thanks for leading me to the right path.

Comment: glad it worked out. that dispatchEvent line makes binding work.  the whole get/set block is what [Bindable] public var data:Object is converted to!  Really cool stuff.  If you wanna get ahead of the game, study this super advanced data binding video.  http://tv.adobe.com/watch/360flex-conference/diving-in-the-data-binding-waters-by-michael-labriola.  It's more about hardcore flex things you can't find anywhere, than just data binding.  best.